# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1ea3' in position 200: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website to get the lottery result with a defined format, it is ok when run on VS code but when run on Git bash it gives me an error. I tried to search and fix but not it didn't worked
I'm using the following code with python 3.8:

```
import requests
import argparse
import bs4
from typing import List

def daily_lottery_prize():
    lot_prizes = []
    ses = requests.Session()
    r = ses.get("http://ketqua1.net")
    tree = bs4.BeautifulSoup(markup=r.text, features="html.parser")
    for node in tree.select('div[id]'):
        if "rs" in node['id'] and "rs_8_0" not in node['id']:
            lot_prizes.append(node.text)                  
    return lot_prizes


def display_lottery_result(lst: List[str]) -> str:
    display = """
    Special prize:      {}
    First prize:          {}
    Second prizes:        {} - {}
    Third prizes:      {} - {} - {}
                       {} - {} - {}
    Fourth prizes:  {} - {} - {} - {}
    Fifth prizes:     {} - {} - {}
                  {} - {} - {}
    Sixth prizes:      {} - {} - {}
    Seventh prizes:     {} - {} - {} - {}
    """.format(*lst)
    return display


def check_prize(your_numbers, daily_prizes):
    if not your_numbers:
        print(display_lottery_result(daily_prizes))
    else:
        last_two_digit = [number[-2:] for number in daily_prizes]
        win_number = []
        for number in your_numbers:
            if number[-2:] in last_two_digit:
                win_number.append(number)

        if not win_number:
            print("You are not lucky this time, "
                  + "Good luck for next time")
        else:
            print("Congratulation, "
                  + "You won traditional lotterry with numbers: "
                  + " - ".join(win_number))


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("your_numbers", nargs="*")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    lot_prizes = daily_lottery_prize()
    check_prize(args.your_numbers, lot_prizes)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I'm getting the following error when run:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex9_2.py", line 83, in <module>
    main()
  File "ex9_2.py", line 79, in main
    check_prize(args.your_numbers, lot_prizes)
  File "ex9_2.py", line 56, in check_prize
    print(display_lottery_result(daily_prizes))
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u1ea3' in position 200: character maps to <undefined>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Please post the full trackback, not just the error message. We need to know the line in *your* code that is causing the exception.

Comment: Hi BoarGules, thanks for your feedback, I've already updated with the full trackback

Comment: More than likely adding `.encode('utf-8')` to the bs4 object would resolve it but not necessarily the ideal way.

Comment: Thanks MDR, I updated the code as you recommended, but it still not work